# How to use a function in one file that was included globally with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, bundle, minify

I have a static Javascript project (no react, vue, etc.) where I am trying to transpile, bundle, and minify my js with webpack. I would like to have bundle.js on my layout page which will include a bunch of global js that runs on all pages and then a page_x.js file that will be on individual pages as needed. The bundle.js file might consist of several other files and should be transpiled to es5 and minified.

With my current setup, the files are running twice. I'm not sure how to fix this. I want the file included globally but also want to be able to call the function as needed. If I delete the import statement from page.js I get the console error, "doSomething" is undefined. If I only include page.js on page.html and not on _layout.html common.js is only logged out on page.html. I want "common" to be logged once on every page and I want doSomething() to be available only on page.js.

Here is an example of it running twice:

common.js

```
console.log("common");
export function doSomething() {
    console.log("do something");
}
```

page.js

```
import {doSomething} from "/common.js";
$(button).click(doSomething);
```

The expected output on page load (before clicking anything) would be:

```
"common"
```

Instead I'm seeing

```
"common"
"common"
```

My webpack.config.js file is as follows:

```
const path = require("path");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const RemoveEmptyScriptsPlugin = require("webpack-remove-empty-scripts");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const WebpackWatchedGlobEntries = require("webpack-watched-glob-entries-plugin");
const CssnanoPlugin = require("cssnano");
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");

const dirName = "wwwroot/dist";

module.exports = (env, argv) => {
    return {
        mode: argv.mode === "production" ? "production" : "development",
        entry: WebpackWatchedGlobEntries.getEntries(
            [
                path.resolve(__dirname, "src/scripts/**/*.js"),
                path.resolve(__dirname, "src/scss/maincss.scss")
            ]),
        output: {
            filename: "[name].js",
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, dirName)
        },
        devtool: "source-map",
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.s[c|a]ss$/,
                    use:
                        [
                            MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                            "css-loader?sourceMap",
                            {
                                loader: "postcss-loader?sourceMap",
                                options: {
                                    postcssOptions: {
                                        plugins: [
                                            CssnanoPlugin
                                        ],
                                        config: true
                                    },
                                    sourceMap: true
                                }
                            },
                            { loader: "sass-loader", options: { sourceMap: true } },
                        ]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(svg|gif|png|eot|woff|ttf)$/,
                    use: [
                        "url-loader",
                    ],
                },
                {
                    test: /\.m?js$/,
                    exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                    use: {
                        loader: "babel-loader",
                        options: {
                            presets: ["@babel/preset-env"]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new WebpackWatchedGlobEntries(),
            new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
            new RemoveEmptyScriptsPlugin(),
            new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                filename: "[name].css"
            })
        ],
        optimization: {
            minimize: true,
            minimizer: [
                new TerserPlugin({
                    extractComments: false,
                })
            ]
        }
    };
};
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Webpack is about building a dependency graph of your application files and finally producing one single bundle.

With your configuration, you are actually trying to use Webpack as a [Multi-entry object configuration](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/) as explained in Webpack documents. The culprit here is `WebpackWatchedGlobEntries` plugin. For each file matched by a glob pattern, it would create a bundle which is not what you want ever. For exmaple, if you have following structure:

```
- src/scripts
    - common.js
    - some
        - page1.js
    - other
        - page2.js
```

This plugin will produce multi-page application. So, you configuration:

```
entry: WebpackWatchedGlobEntries.getEntries(
  [
    path.resolve(__dirname, "src/scripts/**/*.js"),
    path.resolve(__dirname, "src/scss/maincss.scss")
  ]),
```

will internally return an object as:

```
entry: {
  "common": "src/scripts/common.js",
  "some/page1": "src/scripts/some/page1.js",
  "other/page2": "src/scripts/other/page2.js"
}
```

It means if you import `common.js` into `page1.js` and `page2.js`, then you are in producing three bundles and all those bundles will possess the `common` module which would be executed three times.

The solution really depends on how to you want to configure your bundle:

- If you need to bundle as a multi-page application, then you must use [`splitChunk` optimization](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/#optimizationsplitchunks) that allows you to create page specific bundle while keeping shared code separate (`common.js` for example). Keep in mind that you do not really need to manually create a separate bundle for `common.js`. with split chunks, Webpack should do that automatically for you.
- If you need a single bundle, you can literally go ahead and create a single bundle for entire application (most typical workflow with Webpack) and use the same bundle on each page. You can have a common function like `run` that can figure the code to call using URL or some unique page specific identifier. In modern SPA, that is done using routing module.

What I will suggest is to keep things simple. Do not use `WebpackWatchedGlobEntries` plugin. That will complicate things if you are not familiar with Webpack. Keep `entry` simple like this:

```
entry: {
  // Note that you don't need common module here. It would be picked up as part of your page1 and page2 dependency graph
  "page1": "src/scripts/some/page1.js",
  "page2": "src/scripts/other/page2.js"
}
```

Then, enable the splitchunk optimization as:

```
optimization: {
  splitChunks: {
    chunks: 'all'
  }
}
```

Again, there are multiple options to choose from. You can read more details here about [preventing code duplication](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#prevent-duplication).

Comment: Thank you for your response, however, I can't seem to get it to work. I can't add a long enough comment to show my work but basically I added page1 and page2 to the entries as you have above and added splitChunks as above to the optimization tag. I'm now getting just page1 and page2 created with no common.js

Comment: Also, if I'm completely going the wrong direction to solve this let me know. I really just want to take all of my js files, transpile, minify, and package them together into something like site.min.js, page1.minjs, and page2.min.js.

Comment: @Lee, You are almost there. The reason why Webpack is not producing third file is because the `common.js` must not have too much content. By default, Webpack splits the common code into separate file if at least 20KB in size. It is controlled using `splitChunks.minSize` property. Next, chunk != file and thus chunk name is not file name. It would be produced by Webpack automatically and would be typically a number - `648.js`. You can override that using `splitChunks.name` property but that's not a good idea. Read more here - https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/

Comment: What happens to the functions that are not specifically added to any page. For example, global.js is added to my layout.html template. It does things like add event listeners and functions that run on page load of every page. It is never added to any single Page's Js file. It still needs to be transpiled an minimized and included on the site. The functions of that should be available to be called as needed by other pages.

Comment: @Lee, for such files, you should use side-effect imports like `import 'global.js';`.